# Chown & Chmod commands returning Operation not permitted on Hard Disk

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, hard-disk, chown, exfat

I have a raspberry pi 3b+ and am unable to change/give permissions to an external hard disk I've connected to it. A similar question is:

[chown command returning Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559700/chown-command-returning-operation-not-permitted)

Also I've mounted the disk by:

[How to Turn a Raspberry Pi into a Low-Power Network Storage Device](http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/)

I've mounted my hard disk in much the same way. But this is a different case and I'm a beginner so I don't understand most of it. I've mounted the disk as exfat.
The folder I want to chown is nextcloud and if I do `ls -al` I get the following

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8388608 Jul 27 19:09 nextcloud
```

Just as in his case, my folder is also located in `/media/USBHDD1/shares`

I'n currently using `sudo chown pi /media/USBHDDD1/shares/nextcloud` but I'm not permitted to do so. Also and chmod commands don't do anything. I don't get an error, but the permissions aren't changed either.

I don't know what to do to change the permissions.
If I run `/media $  grep USBHDD1 /etc/mtab` it returns:
`/dev/sda2 /media/USBHDD1 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0`

This also occurs when I try to change the permissions of the folder.
Any sort of assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The output of my `mount` command is:
`/dev/sda1 on /media/pi/01D64154A003CBF0 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,uhelper=udisks2)`

I also tried to change my fstab and add uid and gid, no luck.
I understand you cant change permissions with exfat. Which file system should I use?

Comment: what is the output of `mount`?

Comment: exfat => no owner consideration , nor permissions. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison#security

Comment: I added output of mount.

Comment: I've tried the way the above question suggests but no luck.